Prove that $|E\ast f(x)|\le \frac{C_f}{|x|}$ when $|x|\to\infty$ where $E=-\frac1{4\pi |x|}$ and $f\in\mathcal E'(\mathbb R^3)$ is distribution

Suppose $f \in \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}^3)$. Prove the existence of a constant $C_f > 0$ (which may depend on the distribution $f$), such that
$$
   |E * f(x)| \leq \frac{C_f}{|x|}.\quad \text{when}\ |x|\to\infty
   $$
where $E= \frac{|x|^{2-n}}{(2-n)|S^{n-1}|}$. (For $n=3$, $E(x)=-\frac{1}{4\pi |x|}$.)

First, I consider that $E\ast f(x)=\langle f(y),E(x-y)\rangle$. If $f$ is regular distribition (can consider as a locally integrable function), we only need to prove $\displaystyle\left|\int_{\mathbb R^3}\frac{f(y)dy}{|x-y|}\right|\le \frac{C_f}{|x|}$.
UPDATE-- I think I've solved the case for $f$ is $\color{red}{\textbf{regular}}$ distribution:

Considering the support set of $f$ and assuming it's $\{a:|a|<R\}$. Now when $|x|\ge 2R$, we have $\displaystyle\left|\int_{\mathbb R^3}\frac{f(y)dy}{|x-y|}\right|=\left|\int_{|y|\le R}\frac{f(y)dy}{|x-y|}\right|\le \left|\int_{|y|\le R}\frac{f(y)dy}{\left|\frac x 2\right|}\right| \le\frac{\frac83\pi R^3f_\max}{|x|}$.

Is the proof above true?
And how can I deal with the case for $f$ is $\color{red}{\textbf{non-regular}}$ distribution?

In the title you say that $E$ has to be conbsidered as a distribution, but in the body you treat it as a function. Which is it?

What is $\mathcal{E}'$? If it contains $\nabla\delta_0$, then the assertion is false since $\nabla\delta_0*E = \nabla E = c x / |x|^3$

If $\mathcal{E}'$ is $\mathcal{D}'$ (continuous linear functional on $C_c^{\infty}$), then the result cannot be true.

@LL3.14, $\mathcal E'$ is "Distribution space with compact support set". And-- sorry, I wrote one important sentence less: when $|x|\to\infty$. Now it has been fixed.

@LL3.14, I think $\nabla \delta_0$ is in $\mathcal E'$. And it match the condition now (after my modification).

@ShuhaoCao, $\mathcal E'$ is distribution space with compact support set, it seems that $\mathcal D'\subset \mathcal E'$. And now I has update the condition. It should be true now.

@Marco, $E$ is a locally integrable function, I've fixed the typo. Thanks.

@LL3.14, I have updated this problem one more time. Do you have any idea to solve the case for non-regular?
